# How can I get a value from multiple dynamically generated components in React & React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an app with react native.

The components were created as many times as each furniture button was pressed. (Create LuggageDetailCard component by count number)

Each component (LuggageDetailCard) has a categoryType.

How can I have the categoryType for each LugageDetailCard in LugageDetailInfo?

LuggageDetailInfo.tsx

```js
const luggageCard = (count: number, category: string) => {
    const result = [];

    const getCategoryObject = luggageDetailTypeData.filter(
      el => el.category === category,
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      result.push(
        <LuggageDetailCard
          key={i + 1}
          name={getCategoryObject[0].name}
          img={getCategoryObject[0].image}
          i={i}
          categoryObject={getCategoryObject[0]}
        />,
      );
    }
    return result;
  };
```

LuggageDetailCard.tsx

```js
export default function LuggageDetailCard({img, name, i, categoryObject}) {
  const [categoryType, setCategoryType] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginVertical: 15,
        }}>
        <Image
          source={img}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{width: 60, height: 40, marginRight: 5}}
        />
        <Text>
          {name} {i + 1}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          width: '95%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}>
        <CircleRadioButton
          data={categoryObject.type}
          onSelect={(value: string) => setCategoryType(value)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

CircleRadioButton.tsx

```js
export default function CircleRadioButton({data, onSelect}) {
  const [userOption, setUserOption] = useState('');

  const selectHandler = (value: string) => {
    onSelect(value);
    setUserOption(value);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      {data.map((item: itemProps) => {
        return (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => selectHandler(item.value)}
            key={item.id}
            style={[
              {
                borderColor:
                  userOption === item.value
                    ? PRIMARY_COLOR
                    : LIGHT_GRAY_FONT_COLOR,
                backgroundColor:
                  userOption === item.value ? PRIMARY_COLOR : 'white',
              },
              styles.moveBtnPressable,
            ]}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: userOption === item.value ? 'white' : GRAY_COLOR_TEXT,
              }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Have a nice day!

---

```js
const setLuggageCardType = useCallback(
  (type: string, i: number) => {

    // code 1: doesn't work - luggageTyes always []
    setLuggageTypes(prev =>
       prev.map((item, index) => (index === i ? type : item)),
    );

    // code 2: luggageTypes like [{"id": 0, "type": "stoneBed"}, {"id": 1, "type": "superSingle"}]
    let newElement = {id: i, type: type};
    const checkLuggageTypeElement =
      luggageTypes.filter(el => el.id === newElement.id).length !== 0;
    if (checkLuggageTypeElement) {
      // update existing type
      setLuggageTypes([
        ...luggageTypes.slice(0, i),
        newElement,
        ...luggageTypes.slice(i + 1, luggageTypes.length),
      ]);
    } else {
      // add type
      setLuggageTypes(prev => [...prev, newElement]);
    } 
  },
  [luggageTypes],
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that `LuggageDetailInfo` is a valid JSX component and that the created `LuggageDetailCard`s are children of `LuggageDetailInfo`, then we could provide a callback function to the `LuggageDetailCard` components and track them via their indices.

```js
export const LuggageDetailInfo = (props) => {
    
    const [luggageTypes, setLuggageTypes] = useState([]);

    const setLuggageCardType = React.useCallback((type, i) => {
        setLuggageTypes(prev => prev.map((item, index) => index === i ? type : item))
    }, [])

    const luggageCard = (count: number, category: string) => {
        const result = [];

        const getCategoryObject = luggageDetailTypeData.filter(
          el => el.category === category,
        );

        // provide the callback function as a prop
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          result.push(
            <LuggageDetailCard
              key={i + 1}
              setType={setLuggageCardType}
              name={getCategoryObject[0].name}
              img={getCategoryObject[0].image}
              i={i}
              categoryObject={getCategoryObject[0]}
            />,
          );
        }
        return result;
  };

  // component renders `luggageCard`s
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Then, you can use it in `LuggageDetailCard` as follows.

```js
export default function LuggageDetailCard({img, name, i, categoryObject, setType}) {

  const [categoryType, setCategoryType] = useState('');

  function onSetCategoryType(value: string) {
      // call the callback function of parent and provide index
      setType(value, i);
      setCategoryType(value);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginVertical: 15,
        }}>
        <Image
          source={img}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{width: 60, height: 40, marginRight: 5}}
        />
        <Text>
          {name} {i + 1}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          width: '95%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}>
        <CircleRadioButton
          data={categoryObject.type}
          onSelect={(value: string) => onSetCategoryType(value)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The callback function will trigger a state change inside the parent component `LuggageDetailInfo`. We can access each card type via the index in its parent component. This means that we could generate all cards via the `luggageCard` function and then map over all created cards and display or access the type via the index of the map function or with whatever functionality you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I tried it, but sadly, the following error occurred when executing onSetCategoryType function.


`TypeError: setLuggageCardType is not a function. (In 'setLuggageCardType(value, i)', 'setLuggageCardType' is undefined)`


`function onSetCategoryType(value: string) {
    setCategoryType(value);
    setLuggageCardType(value, i);
  }`


`const setLuggageCardType = useCallback((type: string, i: number) => {
    setLuggageTypes(prev =>
      prev.map((item, index) => (index === i ? type : item)),
    );
  }, []);`


how can I solve this?

Comment: Ups, I made a mistake for the names of the props. I have updated my answer. The problem was the destructuring of the `setLuggageCardType` prop. I have named it `setType`.